# Latex words within eqnarray are getting emphasized

Tags: equations, arrays

I have a latex equation within an eqnarray as follows,

```
\begin{eqnarray*}\nonumber
f(\xi) = \min \xi\\
where, \forall n_{j} \in N, \xi = \max (\xi_{1}, \xi_{2}, .., \xi_{j})\\
s.t.\\
\forall n_{j} \in N, \sum_{C_{i} \in C} x_{ij} \leq \eta_{j}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
```

But the problem is that the word "where" is getting emphasized which I do not want. The word max is not getting emphasized as it is reserved word preceded by a "\".

Is there any way I can deemphasize the word "where"? The same is the fate of the letters "s.t." - I also don't want them emphasized inside the eqnarray.

Comment: `eqnarray` gets a lot of scorn from the TeXperts. Consider using the AMS packages instead.

Comment: Yes, you should avoid `eqnarray:` See [\eqnarray vs \align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not that "where" is getting emphasized; rather, it is being typeset as if it were a term in an equation, i.e. `w*h*e*r*e`.  Write `\mbox{where,}` instead (or `\text{where,}` with amsmath).  And you should do the same with `s.t.` on the next line.